# Using Javascript to scan JSON data from youtube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying my hand at searching youtube with the youtube API via Javascript, and as per the google docs on the matter:

```
<div id="agenda"></div>

<script>
  function listEvents(root) {
    var feed = root.feed;
    var entries = feed.entry || [];
    var html = ['<ul>'];


    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
      var entry = entries[i];
      console.log(entry);
      var title = (entry.title.type == 'html') ? entry.title.$t : escape(entry.title.$t);
      var start = (entry['gd$when']) ? entry['gd$when'][0].startTime : "";
      //var id = id.video;  
      //alert(id);

      html.push('<li>', start, ' ', title, '</li>');
    }

    html.push('</ul>');
    document.getElementById("agenda").innerHTML = html.join("");
  }
</script>

<script src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=all the small things&max-results=2&v=2&format=5&orderby=relevance&safeSearch=none&alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents">
</script>
```

this should return data on the song(query) all the small things. and it does! however what im trying to do with this data is grab the id from the json data, but as i am completely new to json (and js for that matter) i seem to be having a hard time doing this. viewing the page with the network tools i can clearly see the section that contains the id:

`"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:9Ht5RZpzPqw"}`

and i can clearly see the data that i want(`9Ht5RZpzPqw`) however no matter how much i scoure json tutorials it makes no sense to me, google seems to do json different than every tutorial ive read. I threw together a jsbin so you can see the results yourself: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/atesaf/1)
Anyone have anyideas? you can see in my code one of the many things i have tried to retrieve that data. Nothing I do seems to work though... Anyone have any ideas or pointers?

```
listEvents({"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns$app":"http://www.w3.org/2007/app","xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$media":"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/","xmlns$gd":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005","xmlns$yt":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007","gd$etag":"W/\"DkEBRn08fip7I2A9WhBaFE8.\"","id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:videos"},"updated":{"$t":"2013-05-24T19:44:17.376Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind","term":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"}],"title":{"$t":"Videos matching: all the small things"},"logo":{"$t":"http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"https://www.youtube.com"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/batch?v=2"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json-in-script&q=all+the+small+things&start-index=1&max-results=2&format=5&safeSearch=none&orderby=relevance&v=2"},{"rel":"service","type":"application/atomsvc+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=atom-service&v=2"},{"rel":"next","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json-in-script&q=all+the+small+things&start-index=3&max-results=2&format=5&safeSearch=none&orderby=relevance&v=2"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"YouTube"},"uri":{"$t":"http://www.youtube.com/"}}],"generator":{"$t":"YouTube data API","version":"2.1","uri":"http://gdata.youtube.com"},"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":1000000},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":1},"openSearch$itemsPerPage":{"$t":2},"entry":[{"gd$etag":"W/\"C0IMSH47eCp7I2A9WhBaFE8.\"","id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:9Ht5RZpzPqw"},"published":{"$t":"2009-06-16T23:16:07.000Z"},"updated":{"$t":"2013-05-24T18:53:09.000Z"},"app$control":{"yt$state":{"$t":"Syndication of this video was restricted.","name":"restricted","reasonCode":"limitedSyndication"}},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind","term":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"},{"scheme":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat","term":"Music","label":"Music"}],"title":{"$t":"blink-182 - All The Small Things"},"content":{"type":"application/x-shockwave-flash","src":"https://www.youtube.com/v/9Ht5RZpzPqw?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ht5RZpzPqw&feature=youtube_gdata"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9Ht5RZpzPqw/responses?v=2"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9Ht5RZpzPqw/related?v=2"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#uploader","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/f2WBemooP2gBBx3lrraNQw?v=2"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9Ht5RZpzPqw?v=2"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"blink-182"},"uri":{"$t":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/blink182VEVO"},"yt$userId":{"$t":"f2WBemooP2gBBx3lrraNQw"}}],"yt$accessControl":[{"action":"comment","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"commentVote","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"videoRespond","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"rate","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"embed","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"list","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"autoPlay","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"syndicate","permission":"allowed"}],"gd$comments":{"gd$feedLink":{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/9Ht5RZpzPqw/comments?v=2","countHint":47078}},"media$group":{"media$category":[{"$t":"Music","label":"Music","scheme":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat"}],"media$content":[{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/v/9Ht5RZpzPqw?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","type":"application/x-shockwave-flash","medium":"video","isDefault":"true","expression":"full","duration":173,"yt$format":5}],"media$credit":[{"$t":"blink182vevo","role":"uploader","scheme":"urn:youtube","yt$display":"blink-182","yt$type":"partner"}],"media$description":{"$t":"Music video by blink-182 performing All The Small Things. (C) 2000 Geffen Records.","type":"plain"},"media$keywords":{},"media$license":{"$t":"youtube","type":"text/html","href":"http://www.youtube.com/t/terms"},"media$player":{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ht5RZpzPqw&feature=youtube_gdata_player"},"media$restriction":[{"$t":"DE","type":"country","relationship":"deny"}],"media$thumbnail":[{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Ht5RZpzPqw/default.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:01:26.500","yt$name":"default"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Ht5RZpzPqw/mqdefault.jpg","height":180,"width":320,"yt$name":"mqdefault"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Ht5RZpzPqw/hqdefault.jpg","height":360,"width":480,"yt$name":"hqdefault"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Ht5RZpzPqw/1.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:00:43.250","yt$name":"start"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Ht5RZpzPqw/2.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:01:26.500","yt$name":"middle"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/9Ht5RZpzPqw/3.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:02:09.750","yt$name":"end"}],"media$title":{"$t":"blink-182 - All The Small Things","type":"plain"},"yt$duration":{"seconds":"173"},"yt$uploaded":{"$t":"2009-06-16T23:16:07.000Z"},"yt$uploaderId":{"$t":"UCf2WBemooP2gBBx3lrraNQw"},"yt$videoid":{"$t":"9Ht5RZpzPqw"}},"gd$rating":{"average":4.900098,"max":5,"min":1,"numRaters":144872,"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"},"yt$statistics":{"favoriteCount":"0","viewCount":"49388829"},"yt$rating":{"numDislikes":"3618","numLikes":"141254"}},{"gd$etag":"W/\"D0UCQH47eCp7I2A9WhBaFEw.\"","id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:ahWmkV0mtvk"},"published":{"$t":"2007-09-19T10:10:21.000Z"},"updated":{"$t":"2013-05-24T17:07:41.000Z"},"app$control":{"yt$state":{"$t":"Syndication of this video was restricted.","name":"restricted","reasonCode":"limitedSyndication"}},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind","term":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"},{"scheme":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat","term":"Music","label":"Music"}],"title":{"$t":"blink 182 all the small things lyrics"},"content":{"type":"application/x-shockwave-flash","src":"https://www.youtube.com/v/ahWmkV0mtvk?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahWmkV0mtvk&feature=youtube_gdata"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ahWmkV0mtvk/responses?v=2"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ahWmkV0mtvk/related?v=2"},{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#uploader","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/KGRY-OpB0xZLqpTZNR418w?v=2"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ahWmkV0mtvk?v=2"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"fuckudumbcuntimnot"},"uri":{"$t":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/fuckudumbcuntimnot"},"yt$userId":{"$t":"KGRY-OpB0xZLqpTZNR418w"}}],"yt$accessControl":[{"action":"comment","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"commentVote","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"videoRespond","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"rate","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"embed","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"list","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"autoPlay","permission":"allowed"},{"action":"syndicate","permission":"denied"}],"gd$comments":{"gd$feedLink":{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments","href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ahWmkV0mtvk/comments?v=2","countHint":5681}},"media$group":{"media$category":[{"$t":"Music","label":"Music","scheme":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat"}],"media$content":[{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/v/ahWmkV0mtvk?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","type":"application/x-shockwave-flash","medium":"video","isDefault":"true","expression":"full","duration":159,"yt$format":5}],"media$credit":[{"$t":"fuckudumbcuntimnot","role":"uploader","scheme":"urn:youtube","yt$display":"fuckudumbcuntimnot"}],"media$description":{"$t":"awsome!!!!!!!!!!!11.","type":"plain"},"media$keywords":{},"media$license":{"$t":"youtube","type":"text/html","href":"http://www.youtube.com/t/terms"},"media$player":{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahWmkV0mtvk&feature=youtube_gdata_player"},"media$restriction":[{"$t":"DE","type":"country","relationship":"deny"}],"media$thumbnail":[{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ahWmkV0mtvk/default.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:01:19.500","yt$name":"default"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ahWmkV0mtvk/mqdefault.jpg","height":180,"width":320,"yt$name":"mqdefault"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ahWmkV0mtvk/hqdefault.jpg","height":360,"width":480,"yt$name":"hqdefault"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ahWmkV0mtvk/1.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:00:39.750","yt$name":"start"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ahWmkV0mtvk/2.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:01:19.500","yt$name":"middle"},{"url":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ahWmkV0mtvk/3.jpg","height":90,"width":120,"time":"00:01:59.250","yt$name":"end"}],"media$title":{"$t":"blink 182 all the small things lyrics","type":"plain"},"yt$duration":{"seconds":"159"},"yt$uploaded":{"$t":"2007-09-19T10:10:21.000Z"},"yt$uploaderId":{"$t":"UCKGRY-OpB0xZLqpTZNR418w"},"yt$videoid":{"$t":"ahWmkV0mtvk"}},"gd$rating":{"average":4.934968,"max":5,"min":1,"numRaters":17130,"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"},"yt$statistics":{"favoriteCount":"0","viewCount":"6287584"},"yt$rating":{"numDislikes":"278","numLikes":"16852"}}]}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `$t` isn't JSON, it's a String Google is using to encode information about the ID. You could do something like this:

```
var vidId = root.feed.id.$t.split('video:')[1];
```

This gets the value of `$t` from the ID object, then looks for the string to the right of `video:`.

Comment: this gives me: Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: I was basing that off the JSON snippet for the id you posted, whats the parent object named?

Comment: I have updated the question with the entire JSON return, if that helps you. thanks in advance

Comment: i tried doing an alert for the vvariable and it returned as undefined, here is the link im working with http://jsbin.com/atesaf/2/edit any chance you can take a look at that and help me out? I appreciate it so much!

Comment: The json that is returned in your example doesn't match what's in your question... are you sure this is the value you want? You might need to read the documentation some more to make sure you are expecting the correct thing.